# Custom tuning grid caret package in R

Tags: r, data.table, linear-regression, r-caret

I have a linear model with a weighting factor that weights the most recent observations.  The weights use a tuning parameter that I would like to optimize using a tuning grid.  A simple example is below:

```
require(data.table)
require(caret)
SMOOTHING_PARAMETER <- 0.2
dt <- data.table(y = rnorm(10),
                 x = rnorm(10))

model <- train(y ~ x,
               data = dt,
               method = "lm",
               weights = (1 + SMOOTHING_PARAMETER) ^(1:nrow(dt)))
```

Is there any way of using the `expand_grid` function in the caret package to find the optimal value for the `TUNING_PARAMETER` variable between (0,1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will have to write a [custom method](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html)to define your own parameters and model. The code for the weights will need to go into the `fit` module.